# An infinite series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Hopefully this question is not a duplication.

Consider the following infinite series:

> $$\LARGE\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{2^k}{1+\frac{1}{x^{2^k}}}$$

We know the answer is $\frac{x}{1-x}$ if $|x|<1$. We also know the partial sum is actually given by

$\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{2^k}{1+\frac{1}{x^{2^k}}}=\frac{\sum_{k=1}^n kx^k}{\sum_{k=0}^n x^k}$. This formula can of course be proved by induction. What I want to know is a way to derive this formula. Since the bottom is the geometric series and the top is its derivative multiplied by $x$, there should be a nice way to derive it.

We know there is a way of finding the sum of the infinite series by appealing to double series, and this is the last thing I want to see.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: There is a closed form for $\frac{\sum_{k=1}^nkx^k}{\sum_{k=1}^nx^k}$, I believe.

Answer (score 3):

To me, the sum can be derived informally as
$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{2^k x^{2^k}}{1+x^{2^k}}
= x \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{d}{dx}\left[ \log(1+x^{2^k}) \right]
= x \frac{d}{dx}\left[ \log\left(\prod_{k=0}^{\infty}1+x^{2^k}\right) \right]\\
= x \frac{d}{dx}\left[ \log\left(\prod_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{1-x^{2^{k+1}}}{1-x^{2^k}}\right) \right]
= -x\frac{d}{dx}\left[\log(1-x)\right] = \frac{x}{1-x}
$$
The key is the summand in the original series is proportional to the derivative of logarithm of something simple. Once we turn the sum of log to a log of product and realize the product is a telescoping one, the rest is just following your nose.

Comment: Thanks. I guess I never thought of "log of product" and telescoping thing. I will do the finite sum (and finite product) and then the differentiation.  I know  if certain thing is uniformly convergent, then infinite summation and differentiation can be interchanged (I am recalling from my head, I don't know the exact formulation).  Anyway this condition should be verified in this case, but I don't bother to check.

Comment: By telescoping I meant the third equality is great so that we can use telescoping.

Comment: This works for the finite sum, too, right?

Comment: @columbus8myhw Yes, this works for finite sum. In fact, if one want to prove the above expression rigorously, One use this trick to derive the correct expression for finite sum and then take the limit.

Comment: @achillehui Is that really necessary? Are there examples where the use of the "informal" logic of your answer give the wrong result?

Comment: @columbus8myhw You never know.  Since log is not defined over the whole complex plane, sum of log isn't always equal to log of product. they can differ by an integer multiple of $2\pi$. Since in terms of $x$, the difference is a locally constant, if you taking derivative afterwards, it usually won't cause any problem. However, if one blindly use the individual piece of the trick, it can bite back at unexpected time. If one use "informal" logic in a reasonable manner, it is usually not that hard to convert it to a real proof.

Answer (score 1):

Let $|x| < 1$ and $k \ge 0$. Using the factorization $1 - x^{2^{k+1}} = (1 - x^{2^k})(1 + x^{2^k})$, we find

$$\frac{2^k x^{2^k}}{1 + x^{2^k}} = \frac{2^kx^{2^k}[(1 + x^{2^k}) - 2x^{2^k}]}{(1 + x^{2^k})(1 - x^{2^k})} = \frac{2^k x^{2^k}}{1 - x^{2^k}} - \frac{2^{k+1}x^{2^{k+1}}}{1 - x^{2^{k+1}}}.$$

So since $\lim\limits_{k\to \infty} \frac{2^k x^{2^k}}{1 - x^{2^k}} = 0$, the series telescopes to $\frac{x}{1 - x}$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(x)$ be the series. Rewriting, we get \begin{eqnarray}f(x)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{2^kx^{2^k}}{1+x^{2^k}}\end{eqnarray}
Let $s_n$ be the $n$-th partial sum. We then have
\begin{align*}
\frac{x}{1-x}-s_n&=\frac{x}{1-x}-\frac{x}{1+x}-\cdots-\frac{2^nx^{2^n}}{1+x^{2^n}}\\
&=\frac{2^{n+1}x^{2^{n+1}}}{1+x^{2^{n+1}}}
\end{align*}
One can show that the above tends to 0 as $n\to \infty$, for $|x|<1$.

Comment: Um....$\frac{2x^2}{1-x^2}+\frac{2x^2}{1+x^2}$ seems to be $\frac{4x^2}{1-x^4}$.......

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the mistake in my first attempt. I've corrected it.